# Get base 64 info from upload

Tags: reactjs

I have an upload component from ant design library.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import {
  Form,
  Select,
  InputNumber,
  Switch,
  Radio,
  Slider,
  Button,
  Upload,
  Rate,
  Checkbox,
  Row,
  Col,
} from 'antd';
import { UploadOutlined, InboxOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const { Option } = Select;
const formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 6,
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 14,
  },
};

const normFile = e => {
  console.log('Upload event:', e);

  if (Array.isArray(e)) {
    return e;
  }

  return e && e.fileList;
};

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
  };
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: false,
});
function getBase64(img, callback) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => callback(reader.result));
  reader.readAsDataURL(img);
}
const handleChange = info => {
    if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
        setState({loading: true});
        return;
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
        // Get this url from response in real world.
        getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, imageUrl =>
            setState({
                imageUrl,
                loading: false,
            }),
        );
    }
};
function beforeUpload(file) {
  const isJpgOrPng = file.type === 'image/jpeg' || file.type === 'image/png';
  if (!isJpgOrPng) {
      console.error('You can only upload JPG/PNG file!');
  }
  const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
  if (!isLt2M) {
    console.error('Image must smaller than 2MB!');
  }
  return isJpgOrPng && isLt2M;
}


const uploadButton = (
    <div>
        <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload img</div>
    </div>
);
const {imageUrl} = state;
  return (
    <Form
      name="validate_other"
      {...formItemLayout}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      initialValues={{
        'input-number': 3,
        'checkbox-group': ['A', 'B'],
        rate: 3.5,
      }}
    >
      
      <Form.Item
        name="upload"
        label="Upload"
        valuePropName="fileList"
        getValueFromEvent={normFile}
      >
               <Upload
                listType="picture-card"
                className="avatar-uploader"
                showUploadList={false}
                action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
                beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
                onChange={handleChange}
                
            >
                {imageUrl ? <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" style={{width: '100%'}}/> : uploadButton}
            </Upload>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 12,
          offset: 6,
        }}
      >
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          get data from upload
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Now i have an issue when i upload an image and after that click on `upload img` button. I don't get the base 64 data of image in `console.log('Received values of form: ', values);` 
Question: How, when i will click on that button to get data as `base64`?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-grass-sqzl1?file=/index.js:0-2944

Comment: do you solve it? i think all you need is changing `normFile` function to return your base64 instead of file

Comment: @ParhamHeidari, how to do this?

Comment: https://ant.design/components/form/

in the last one there is an example

Comment: @ParhamHeidari, could you help, i have the same issue.